# Error when copying, column type mysteriously re-set and then length violated

Tags: python, sql, python-3.x, postgresql, psycopg2

Getting the following error:

```
psycopg2.errors.StringDataRightTruncation: value too long for type character varying(64)
CONTEXT:  COPY fngenderguessallprospssinglebatchv1, line 5396, column firstname: "Unsub-Ylvsccfmmlvnsclscdfhgdhvnrswzfrrbsfrffsasdfefasdfccqwtsb@wherever.Com"
```

I'm trying to create tables in a schema that I've created (called `dbo`, which is not default for me).  First I make the tables, then I try to read from csv files to pupulate them.  Note: at first, I had specified `Varchar(64)` as the `type` for the columns of the table.  After seeing the above error, I changed that to `Varchar(200)` and then simply `Varchar`, but the error wasn't resolved.  Finally, I tried the type `Text`, but I'm still getting the exact same error!  So, why is my prescription of `type` being ignored, followed by generation of the above error (which suggests that `type` is now `Varchar(64)`, after I tried to make things as flexible as possible???

Create tables:

```
import psycopg2
from psycopg2 import sql
import os
import glob

connection = psycopg2.connect('postgresql://porter_test2:porter_test2@localhost:5432/porter_test2')
print("Establishing database connection")

db_schema_name = "dbo"

csvPath = r"D:\work_files\porter_project\demo_setup\csv_files"
csvPath = csvPath + "\\"



# Loop through each CSV
for file_name in glob.glob(csvPath+"*.csv"):
    

    table_name = file_name.replace(csvPath, "").replace(".csv", "")
    if len(db_schema_name) > 0:
        table_name = db_schema_name + "." + table_name
    
    # Open file
    fileInput = open(file_name, "r")

    # Extract first line of file
    firstLine = fileInput.readline().strip()

    # Split columns into an array [...]
    columns = firstLine.split(",")

    sqlQueryCreate = 'DROP TABLE IF EXISTS ' + table_name + ";\n"
    sqlQueryCreate += 'CREATE TABLE ' + table_name + "("


    # Define columns for table
    for column in columns:
        #sqlQueryCreate += column + " VARCHAR,\n"
        sqlQueryCreate += column + " TEXT,\n"

    sqlQueryCreate = sqlQueryCreate[:-2]
    sqlQueryCreate += ");"

    cursor = connection.cursor()
    cursor.execute(sqlQueryCreate)
    connection.commit()
    cursor.close()


connection.close()
```

Populate tables (where the error "happens"):

```
import psycopg2
from psycopg2 import sql
import os
import glob
import csv

connection = psycopg2.connect('postgresql://porter_test2:porter_test2@localhost:5432/porter_test2')
print("Establishing database connection")

# specify database schema name
db_schema_name = "dbo"

csvPath = r"D:\work_files\porter_project\demo_setup\csv_files"

csvPath = csvPath + "\\"



# Loop through each CS
for file_name in glob.glob(csvPath+"*.csv"):
    table_name = file_name.replace(csvPath, "").replace(".csv", "")

    copy_sql = "COPY {table_name} FROM '{file}' WITH CSV HEADER DELIMITER as ',';".format(
        table_name = table_name,
        file = file_name,
    )

    with open(file_name, 'r') as f:
        cursor = connection.cursor()
        cursor.copy_expert(sql=copy_sql, file=f)
        connection.commit()
        cursor.close()


connection.close()
```

Comment: Best bet is the table you made the field change to `varchar(64)` --> `varchar` --> `text` is not the same as you are doing the `COPY` to. Check: 1) You are connecting to same database in each case and/or 2) You are using same  *schema_name.table_name* combination.

Comment: you're probably right.  this stuff is tough for me as a novice!  thanks for the support

Comment: When creating the table, you are specifying a schema name, but when doing COPY, you do not appear to be doing that.

Comment: The line ```table_name = db_schema_name + "." + table_name``` seems to just make the table ```dbo.mytable``` in the ```public``` schema, instead of making ```mytable``` in the ```dbo``` schema.  Very confused by this.

Comment: Nothing confusing about it `'dbo' + '.'  + 'mytable'`  --> `'dbo.mytable'`. A schema qualified name is `"dbo"."mytable"`. To do dynamic SQL in `psycopg2` properly read [sql](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/sql.html) in particular the *class psycopg2.sql.Identifier* section.